# Visual Studio no se puede ejecutar si la instalación está en curso

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Al inicial Visual Studio 2019 me sale el siguiente error:

> No se puede ejecutar si la instalación está en curso.

¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo?

Gracias

Comment: Tal vez es que la instalación está en curso, finalizandola o actualizando. Mira [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27538833) a ver si te ayuda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay que esperar a que se termine de ejecutar un proceso de trasfondo y entonces deja ingresar normalmente. En mi caso fue entre 5 y 10 minutos.

Answer (score 0):

Solo ve al administrador de tareas, y ahi cierra el Visual Studio que tiene abierto, y ya. vuelve a ejecutar el programa.